# MVC : Page is not being redirected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am practicing on MVC 4 to save data into database. System takes Employee's First name, Last name, Joining date, Date of birth, email and contact number.

Data is being saved but I want it to show success message on the same screen. I have used jquery for it.

```
  function onSucessSaveemployee(data) {
    if (data.Status == "OK") {
        ShowAlertInline(getMessage("Insertupdateemployeemsg"), SUCESSTYPE);
        setTimeout(function () {
            Navigator(CancelEmployeeurl, 'pageredirect', '')
        }, 10000);
```

it shows message for a blink of second the redirects to http://localhost:54320/InsertUpdateemployee with following message given below.

```
{"Data":null,"Status":"OK","Name":"Save Employee","RedirectTo":null,"ErrorInfo":null,"Message":"Employee detail Inserted"}
```

What am i doing wrong?, i will provide more information if required.

code for showAlertInline

```
    function ShowAlertInline(message, messageType) {
            jQuery('#alertMessage > p').html(message)
            var alertObj = jQuery('#alertMessage');
            jQuery(alertObj).removeClass('alert-error').removeClass('alert-      success').removeClass('alert-warning');
            if (messageType == ERRORTYPE) {
            jQuery(alertObj).addClass('alert-error');
        }
            else if (messageType == SUCESSTYPE) {
            jQuery(alertObj).addClass('alert-success');
        }
            else if (messageType == WARRNIGTYPE) {
            jQuery(alertObj).addClass('alert-warning');
        }
            jQuery(alertObj).show();
            setTimeout(HideAlertInline, 10000);

code for getmessage

    function getMessage(key, placeHolders) {
        LanguageCurrent = 'en'; //Default English
        if (localStorage) {
            if (localStorage.LanguageCurrent != undefined) {
                LanguageCurrent = localStorage.LanguageCurrent;
            }
        }
```

Employee Controller has this code:

```
public partial class MasterController : BaseController
    {   
      public ActionResult EmployeeDetail(String id)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                EmployeeModel employeeModel = new EmployeeModel();
                employeeModel = masterRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);
                employeeModel.Department = masterRepository.Department();
                return View("Employee", employeeModel);
            }
            else
            {
                EmployeeModel employeeModel = new EmployeeModel();
                employeeModel.Department = masterRepository.Department();
                return View("Employee", employeeModel);
            }
        }
            public ActionResult SaveEmployee(EmployeeModel employeeModel)
        {
              AjaxResponse objAjaxResponse = new AjaxResponse();
              objAjaxResponse.Name = "Save Employee";
              if(employeeModel != null)
          {
               employeeModel = masterRepository.Insertupdateemployee(employeeModel);
               if (employeeModel.EmployeeID != 0)
            {
                  objAjaxResponse.Status = AjaxResponseStatusCodes.Ok;
                  objAjaxResponse.Message = Resources.Resource.EmployeeDetailUpdate;
             }
                 else
             {
                  objAjaxResponse.Status = AjaxResponseStatusCodes.Ok;
                  objAjaxResponse.Message = Resources.Resource.EmployeeDetailInsert;
             }
             }
                else
             {
                  return View("Employee", employeeModel);
             }
       }
```

For InsertUpdateemployee.

```
    function Insertupdateemployee() {
        var currentForm = jQuery("#frmEmployeeDetail");
        if (CheckErrors(currentForm)) {
            var formData = currentForm.serialize();
            AjaxCall({
                url: InsertUpdateUrl,
                postData: formData,
                httpmethod: 'POST',
                calldatatype: 'JSON',
                sucesscallbackfunction: 'onSucessSaveemployee',
                isAsync:false
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is not where it ends. I debugged it then I found out it is debugging twice and data is saved twice but sometimes on putting debugger through Jquery using firebug it runs just fine and data is saved once. after removing debugger i am facing all kind of problems.

1> Page not Being re-directed and showing message

```
{"Data":null,"Status":"OK","Name":"Save Employee","RedirectTo":null,"ErrorInfo":null,"Message":"Employee detail Inserted"} on page with
```

url http://localhost:54320/InsertUpdateemployee with following message given below.

2> Data being saved twice in database.
3> running perfectly when putting debug points on methods.
Please help me.

I already cant ask more questions as I m blocked from asking questions on this site. i am not able to learn further as i am irritated by this problem.

Comment: What is `ShowAlertInline`? Can you share the code of `ShowAlertInline` and `getMessage`?

Comment: @Satpal . I m working on a pre-built application. this works on other pages that have been developed but it does not works on my page.

Comment: When you submit the form, are you using jQuery to submit it or is the HTML doing it?

Comment: @JamieR I used Jquery . I debugged it again and now i am seeing it is not going in onSucessSaveemployee(data). earlier it was but even then it was not working.

Comment: Can you show the jQuery code you are using to send the data?

Comment: function Insertupdateemployee()
{
    var currentForm = jQuery("#frmEmployeeDetail");
   if (CheckErrors(currentForm)){
    var formData = currentForm.serialize();
    AjaxCall({ url: InsertUpdateurl, postData: formData, httpmethod: 'POST', calldatatype: 'JSON', sucesscallbackfunction: 'onSucessSaveemployee' });
       
    }
}

Comment: jQuery("#btnSave").on('click', function () { Insertupdateemployee() });